# Как заставить текст обтекать картинку?

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я тут хочу чтобы параграф под картинкой был возле картинки, а не под. Как это сделать ?

Код:

```css
    html {width:100%; height:100%;}
    
    body {
     background:url(../images/goodwp1.jpg) top left repeat-x #afafaf;
     
     min-width:1200px;
     height:100%; 
     }
     nav {
      
      text-align: center;
    }
      h1{
                
                font-size: 50px;
                color:white;
                margin: 0px;
                text-align: center;
                display: table-cell;
                vertical-align: middle;
            }
    nav > ul {
      list-style: none;
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
      display: inline-block;
      background: #ddd;
      border-radius: 5px;
    }
    nav > ul > li {
      float: left;
      width: 150px;
      height: 65px;
      line-height: 65px;
      position: relative;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      font-size: 14px;
      color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    nav > ul > li:hover {
      background: #d5d5d5;
      border-radius: 5px;
    }
    
    ul.drop-menu {
      position: absolute;
      top: 100%;
      left: 0%;
      width: 100%;
      padding: 0;
    }
    ul.drop-menu li {
      background: #666;
      color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
    }
    ul.drop-menu li:hover {
      background: #606060;
    }
    ul.drop-menu li:last-child {
      border-radius: 0px 0px 5px 5px;
    }
    
    ul.drop-menu li {
      display: none;
    }
    
    li:hover > ul.drop-menu li {
      display: block;
    }
```

```html
    <body>
    
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li>Ana Səhifə
          <ul class="drop-menu menu-#{i}">
            <li>uno</li>
            <li>dos</li>
            <li>tres</li>
            <li>cuatro</li>
            <li>cinco</li>
            <li>seis</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>style 2
          <ul class="drop-menu menu-#{i}">
            <li>uno</li>
            <li>dos</li>
            <li>tres</li>
            <li>cuatro</li>
            <li>cinco</li>
            <li>seis</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>style 3
          <ul class="drop-menu menu-#{i}">
            <li>uno</li>
            <li>dos</li>
            <li>tres</li>
            <li>cuatro</li>
            <li>cinco</li>
            <li>seis</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>style 4
          <ul class="drop-menu menu-#{i}">
            <li>uno</li>
            <li>dos</li>
            <li>tres</li>
            <li>cuatro</li>
            <li>cinco</li>
            <li>seis</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <div style="margin:0px auto; width:55%; background:white;">
       <center><div style=" margin-top:10px;width:100%; background:url(html/images/bg_slogan.gif) left top repeat-x;"> <h1 style="color:white;padding-top:10px;padding-bottom:10px;" class="animated zoomIn">EasyShop.az</h3></div></center>
     <div id="grid1">
        <center>      <h3 class="">Dəyərli zamanınıza qənaət edib sifarişləri dəqiqələr içində edin.</h3></center>
    
     <img src="images/cargo.jpg">         <p style="position:relative;text-align: center; display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;" >Bizim fikrimizcə,ən böyük üstünlüyümüz qısa zaman içində ürəyiniz istəyən əşyanı/geyimi dəqiqələr içində sifariş edə bilməyinizdir. Qısa zamandan əlavə hər şey 100% təhlükəsiz və sərfəli qiymətə əldə olunur.Sifariş və onun necə olunması haqqda məlumatları "Sifariş" bölməsində tapa bilərsiniz.</p>
    
     </div>
    </div>
     
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: размести в разных блоках, примерно как тут https://jsfiddle.net/afsgaq3o/

Comment: я сделал ни как не поменяется такая проблема как видите параграф внутри div-a как только float right он вышел из div -а

Comment: Можно в word настроить

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что бы текст обтекал картинку нужно добавить атрибут `align`.

```html
<img src="http://s00.yaplakal.com/pics/pics_original/4/6/8/8310864.jpg" align="left" width="300px">
<p>Bizim fikrimizcə,ən böyük üstünlüyümüz qısa zaman içində ürəyiniz istəyən əşyanı/geyimi dəqiqələr içində sifariş edə bilməyinizdir. Qısa zamandan əlavə hər şey 100% təhlükəsiz və sərfəli qiymətə əldə olunur.Sifariş və onun necə olunması haqqda məlumatları "Sifariş" bölməsində tapa bilərsiniz.</p>
```

Пример: https://jsfiddle.net/afsgaq3o/1/

Comment: да параграф поменял место есть проблема одна картинка вышла из div

Comment: Потому что картинка получает статус плавающего блока, что бы исправить ошибку, нужно остановить расчет позиций относительно него. Для этого используют clearfix: https://jsfiddle.net/afsgaq3o/2/

Comment: Блогадарен вам! Очень помогли!

Comment: В 2017 еще кто-то использует атрибут align?

Comment: @mJeevas почему бы и нет :) Но да, правильней будет делать float: left . Но нужно знать и базовое...

Answer (score 1):

float: left; для обьекта обтекаемого текстом